# Link jQuery-UI/Kendo-UI to make live changes to elements in page designer

Tags: css, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I apologize if the title was not clear enough. I am working on a project where a user can design a page (something like [Wix](http://www.wix.com)). I am continuing on a project left in-complete by some developer. The sequence of action is.

- The user clicks on a link which adds an element on the page (e.g. textElement, picture, slider...)
- There is an edit button for each element. Clicking which opens a dialog box.
- On the dialog box there are sliders and color picker drawn using Kendo-UI. Using them the user can change the style settings for the element (e.g Font-Color, BG-Color, Font Size...)

What I want now is to apply/show the changes live on that element. I have the id available for each element. I can bind each of the style selectors and apply the changes live to the text element. But that does not seem the right choice as in future we might add another style selector in the dialog box, and that would mean adding the code for binding this new selector.

What I wanted to know was that is there an alternate or preferably easy way to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Share some code with the basic idea that you follow, cause it's not getting clear what you did. It sounds like you can use the [MVVM](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/mvvm/index.html) framework feature to help you for that.